# How create an installer for c# autocad plugin + custom menu

Tags: c#, plugins, autocad

I would like to know how to create a an installer (.exe or .bat) to deploy an AutoCad plugin developed with C #. The installer will have 2 tasks: auto load the plugin DLL and auto load a .cui file which will be created as user interface of the plugin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use InnoSetup to create exe installer with specified cuix, dll, and lisp file, where in lisp file You may use command `netload` to load C# , and command `menuload` to load cui file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Autoloader](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/01/autodesk-autoloader-white-paper.html) mechanism. Just create a .bundle folder containing a PackageContents.xml file and your .dll and .cuix files. Then, simply depoly it in an ApplicationPlugins folder with any installer.